# How to fire a http call before user close the website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to make a chatting a website. In that  users are also have offline or online status..If users are logged in than setting the user online and if user logged out or closed the tab or close the website than setting the user offline..Currently i am using beforeunload event. It was working just fine when my backend was on localhost but as soon as i shifted my backend to a host machine than upon closing tab users status isn't changing from offline to online..

```
// on app.component.ts file..
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload') changeStatus() {
   this.http.get('some url to make the users status offline').subscribe()
}
```

this one isn't working upon shifting the backend to host mechine..i suppose thats because it's an asynchronous call and browser killing that thread before completing..so this asynchronous call isn't finsihing.. i tried to use  `navigator.sendBeacon()` but the main problem is i can't find any solution to send a bearer token through `navigator.sendBeacon()` method and my http call is really rely upon that bearer token..so how can i send some http request before the user close the tab so in the database the users status changes to offline? I am using angular...

Comment: There is the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) but you can probably do it even simpler by doing a periodic check if the user is active (can be reached). If they aren't, then they are offline.

Comment: i have to change the users status in database..so i need to make httpcall that will change the users status to offline in database..and i mentioned above that i can't find a way to send bearer token header through beacon api.

Comment: You could open a websocket connection (or socket.io) and when the socket gets closed, mark the user as offline at the server side.

Comment: @sahilaktar if you require *the client* to notify you of its status, then your information can be incorrect in the database. A trivial example is if a computer/browser crashes. Then the user is *not* online but you've not reflected their real status in the database. You can also have users deliberately manipulate that and send the offline call without actually being online. Whether that's malicious depends on whether the outcome can be abused.

Comment: Beacon really is the safest option in this case. You’d have to make a custom endpoint on your API that accepts a payload (with a uid for example) instead of a header token.

Comment: @VLAZ yes.that is another problem..i am aware of that if a user gets offline then his status will not be changed in database..can you give me some suggestions that how should i change the status in database if user get offline or i shouln't save the status at database at all..then in which process i can get that if a user is online or not? i can  make simple calls to the users to check if he is online or not but i want this to make realtime so as soon as he is offline i get notified.

Comment: Don't trust the client to update it. Manage everything from the backend. You can keep a periodic update (a hearbeat) that checks in with the backend every 1s or similar interval which will keep the user "online". You can do a similar thing by opening a socket between client and server.

Comment: @VLAZ can you please give me some examples or some link to see how can i change the users status totally from the backend side.